# Add characters to strings in a data frame based on row names

Tags: r, string, dataframe

Let's say I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    number  text

 1   3      hello
 2   3      this
 3   3      is
 4   3      a
 5   3      text
```

and I have a second data frame that looks like this:

```
    number  text

 1   3      hello
 5   3      text
```

and my final output should look like this:

```
    number  text

 1   3      <b>hello</b>
 2   3      this
 3   3      is
 4   3      a
 5   3      <b>text</b>
```

What would be the best way to achieve this result?

(the first column represents the row names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, text := paste0("<b>", text, "</b>"), on = "text"]
df1
#     number         text
#1:      3 <b>hello</b>
#2:      3         this
#3:      3           is
#4:      3            a
#5:      3  <b>text</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
text <- c("hello", "this", "is", "a", "text")
bold <- c("hello", "text")
index <- text%in%bold
text[index] <- paste("<b>", text[index], "</b>", sep = "")
```